# Run game local (file:///) Construct 2

Tags: android, construct-2

I have a question like the one is asked here in this link: [Solution: Run game local (file:///) Construct 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094641/solution-run-game-local-file-construct-2)

I did the third step of the solution. I added

```
self.loadProject(FULL_CONTENT_INSIDE_MY_DATA.JS); return;
```

just after

```
xhr.open("GET", datajs_filename, true);
var supportsJsonResponse = false;
```

in c2runtime.js. But when I test the game in my Android App, I only see the first page of construct; The game cannot be loaded and the first page of construct remains as an image.

A piece of my code:

```
Runtime.prototype.requestProjectData = function ()
    {
        var self = this;
        var xhr;
        if (this.isWindowsPhone8)
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        else
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var datajs_filename = "data.js";
        if (this.isWindows8App || this.isWindowsPhone8 || this.isWindowsPhone81 || this.isWindows10)
        datajs_filename = "data.json";
        //xhr.open("GET", datajs_filename, true); <-- I commented this line
        var supportsJsonResponse = false;
        self.loadProject(FULL_CONTENT_INSIDE_MY_DATA.JS); return;
```

Comment: Just run it through a localhost server use Wamp or Xampp

Comment: @K-Alex If you mean using a wamp or xampp server for android, I prefer not to; because I want my application run independently. So I solved my problem by developing a simple server by myself and then when going to the game activity, I start that server. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run it through a localhost server 
use Wamp or Xampp

Comment: Thanks. I create my own web-server at last. It worked perfectly.